# Want to change the arrow from large size to small size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular6, angular-ui

I am using angular2-multiselect and by default arrow size is large I want to decrease the size of the dropdown arrow.

```
<angular2-multiselect
  class="form-control"
  [data]="dropdownList1"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
  (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>

<angular2-multiselect
  class="form-control"
  [data]="dropdownList1"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
  (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code in your style sheet

```
:host /deep/ 

.selected-list .fa-angle-down{
  font-size: 8pt !important;

}

.selected-list .fa-angle-up{
      font-size: 8pt !important;

    }
```

Comment: This will decrease the font size of your icon , and same apply for .fa-angle-up